# Running Python code in parallel from Rust with rust-cpython

Tags: python, rust, cpython

I'm trying to speed up a data pipeline using Rust. The pipeline contains bits of Python code that I don't want to modify, so I'm trying to run them as-is from Rust using [rust-cpython](https://docs.rs/cpython/0.4.1/cpython/) and multiple threads. 
However, the performance is not what I expected, it's actually the same as running the python code bits sequentially in a single thread.

Reading the documentation, I understand when invoking the following, you actually get a pointer to a single Python interpreter that can only be created once, even if you run it from multiple threads separately.

```
    let gil = Python::acquire_gil();
    let py = gil.python();
```

If that's the case, it means the Python GIL is actually preventing all parallel execution in Rust as well. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Here's the code of my test:

```rust
use cpython::Python;
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::time::Instant;

#[test]
fn python_test_parallel() {
    let start = Instant::now();

    let (tx_output, rx_output) = mpsc::channel();
    let tx_output_1 = mpsc::Sender::clone(&tx_output);
    thread::spawn(move || {
        let gil = Python::acquire_gil();
        let py = gil.python();
        let start_thread = Instant::now();
        py.run("j=0\nfor i in range(10000000): j=j+i;", None, None).unwrap();
        println!("{:27} : {:6.1} ms", "Run time thread 1, parallel", (Instant::now() - start_thread).as_secs_f64() * 1000f64);
        tx_output_1.send(()).unwrap();
    });

    let tx_output_2 = mpsc::Sender::clone(&tx_output);
    thread::spawn(move || {
        let gil = Python::acquire_gil();
        let py = gil.python();
        let start_thread = Instant::now();
        py.run("j=0\nfor i in range(10000000): j=j+i;", None, None).unwrap();
        println!("{:27} : {:6.1} ms", "Run time thread 2, parallel", (Instant::now() - start_thread).as_secs_f64() * 1000f64);
        tx_output_2.send(()).unwrap();
    });

    // Receivers to ensure all threads run
    let _output_1 = rx_output.recv().unwrap();
    let _output_2 = rx_output.recv().unwrap();
    println!("{:37} : {:6.1} ms", "Total time, parallel", (Instant::now() - start).as_secs_f64() * 1000f64);
}
```

Comment: Python code can only be executed from a single thread at a time. There is nothing preventing Rust code from being run in other threads while the Python code is running in one thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CPython implementation of Python does not allow executing Python *bytecode* in multiple threads at the same time. As you note yourself, the *global interpreter lock* (GIL) prevents this.

We don't have any information on what exactly your Python code is doing, so I'll give a few general hints how you could improve the performance of your code.

- If your code is I/O-bound, e.g. reading from the network, you will generally get nice performance improvements from using multiple threads. Blocking I/O calls will release the GIL before blocking, so other threads can execute during that time.
- Some libraries, e.g. NumPy, internally release the GIL during long-running library calls that don't need access to Python data structures. With these libraries, you can get performance improvements for multi-threaded, CPU-bound code even if you only write pure Python code using the library.
- If your code is CPU-bound and spends most of its time executing Python bytecode, you can often use multipe *processes* rather than threads to achieve parallel execution. The [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) in the Python standard library helps with this.
- If your code is CPU-bound, spends most of its time executing Python bytecode *and* can't be run in parallel processes because it accesses shared data, you can't run it in multiple threads in parallel – the GIL prevents this. However, even without the GIL, you can't just run sequential code in parallel without changes in *any* language. Since you have concurrent access to some data, you need to add locking and possibly make algorithmic changes to prevent data races; the details of how to do this depend on your use case. (And if you *don't* have concurrent data access, you should use processes instead of threads – see above.)

Beyond parallelism, a good way to speed up Python code with Rust is to *profile* your Python code, find the *hot spots* where most of the time is spent, and *rewrite* these bits as Rust functions that you call from your Python code. If this doesn't give you enough of a speedup, you can *combine* this approach with parallelism – preventing data races is generally easier to achieve in Rust than in most other languages.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The situation matches the third option in your list, the code is a mix of Pandas and Numpy operations that are CPU-bound.

Comment: I will try adding generated wrap-around Python Python to use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). The advice on rewriting Python bits in Rust is also good, but for various reasons this would have deep-reaching impacts on the projects, so I'll keep this as a second-line option.

Comment: Actually, a first step before rewriting the hot functions in Rust is to look at their implementation and see whether it can be improved in Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you use py03 bindings you can use the allow_threads method and callbacks to free the GIL for faster parralelism: https://pyo3.rs/v0.13.2/parallelism.html